# I have no Navigation Bar in a view called with an IBAction?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, ibaction

My main menu (a ViewController) is embedded in a NavigationController that I added in the storyboard in Xcode4.
I have a button in my menu, displaying a new view. To display it I use :

```
- (IBAction) display : (id) sender
{
    if(!anotherView) anotherView = [[AnotherView alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherView" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:anotherView animated:NO];
}
```

My other view is correctly displayed with all its objects and elements. Excluding my NavigationController's bar, that doesn't appear. Why ?

Thanks for your advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are presenting the view `modally` what you probably meant was

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherView animated:YES]
```

of course what you really want to do is not mix and match storyboard and non storyboard flows unnecessarily like this and have the storyboard do this for you

Answer (score 1):

you are presenting your viewController modally. If you want to use the navigation controller you have to push your view onto the navigation stack.

replace

```
[self presentModalViewController:anotherView animated:NO];
```

with

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still present your view modally without losing the navigation bar. Try this code:

```
AnotherView *tempAnotherView = [[AnotherView alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherView" bundle:nil];
[self setAnotherView:tempAnotherView];
[tempAnotherView release];

UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.anotherView] autorelease];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

Hope it helps! :)